# Removing variations of Japanese characters from list

Tags: .net, sorting, unicode

QUESTION:

In .net (v4.5) I have a list of Japanese symbols containing say `あ, い, う, え, お, か, き, く, け, こ, が, ぎ, ぐ, げ, ご, さ, し, す, せ, そ, ざ, じ, ず, ぜ, ぞ`.

How can I remove phonetic variations from the list, so change the above list to `あ, い, う, え, お, か, き, く, け, こ, さ, し, す, せ, そ`?

A solution in either C# or VB would be fine.

(See below for some information as to why I am trying to do this)

BACKGROUND:

I have an MS Access database table containing a list of city towns in Japanese in one column and their reading in hiragana in the adjacent column, like this:

```
町名          ふりがな
------------------------
鵜沼朝日町   うぬまあさひまち
上中屋町     かみなかやちょう
小佐野町     こざのちょう
下切町       しもぎりちょう
```

町名 is the town name and ふりがな is the reading in hiragana.

I need to display a form which will allow to search through the list of districts.

There is a system (written in VB.NET) that is currently in place, where the user selects the first symbol (hiragana) from the reading and then gets a list of the towns whose name start with that symbol to choose from.

I am updating that system and have thought I could greatly simplify the existing code, but have run into a snag...

I am making a list of the first reading symbol using the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT([ふりがな], 1) FROM MyTable
```

Which works fine for getting the list of first symbols for the user to choose from. I then use that list to populate a winforms dropdownlist on my search interface from which the user can choose the first symbol, which then populates a listbox with all the available towns.

The problem I have is the query returns all symbols (as it should) including phonetic variations, like が, じ, ぴ etc., which I do not actually want in my list as in Japan phonetic variations are normally ignored when grouping symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it without a lookup table, you could take advantage of Unicode normalisation.

If you normalise a letter that has a diacritical mark (including Japanese voiced marks) to Normal Form D, you'll get a decomposed base letter and combining diacritical. Just take the first of those characters and you've got what you want.

```
name.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Substring(0, 1)
```

Comment: That works indeed. Funny I thought I tried to normalize to form D on Friday... must have been dreaming. Much better answer than mine or the one above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim x As New List(Of Char) ''containing the chars to be removed
For Each y In x
    queryresult.Replace(y, "")
Next
```

If you know which is which:

```
Dim phonetics As New List(Of Char)
Dim actuals As New List(Of Char)
For i = 0 To phonetics.Count - 1
     queryresult.Replace(phonetics(i), actuals(i))
Next
```

Another way is:

```
Dim actual As String = queryresult.Split(" ")(0)
```

Comment: Yes, this method occurred to me too, but I was wondering if there actually is a way to convert phonetic variations back to the base form.

Comment: I thought of using a dictionary if I did it this way. I'll award you the answer if I don't get an answer on how to do this without a list by tomorrow :)

Comment: You understood just fine, this method works just fine. What I would like to know is if there is a method for me to go through the original list and convert the phonetic variations to the base form without having to resort to setting up a list of conversions first. Via the System.Globalization namespace or somesuch.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, but in the end I came up with an answer which is more like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out a way.
Katakanas can be converted to single byte charatacters, which results in a single byte kana and optionally a second single byte for the modifier ("dakuten" in Japanese).

So, modified kanas can be elimited from the list by doing a check like this (in `VB`)

```
if StrConv(StrConv(kana, VbStrConv.Katakana), VbStrConv.Narrow).Length > 1 then
    ...
end if
```

Any string that has a length greater than one is a modifed sound.

It gets trickier in `C#` for the conversion, but the principle would be the same. This does not work with hiraganas, because they cannot be half-width, so t is important to first do the katakana conversion.